# Json parsing with Apostrophes (Single Quote) in BrightScript

Tags: json, roku, urldecode, brightscript, scenegraph

I use ParseJson() to parse JSON information retrieved from a server. Everything works OK except some value includes "&#8217；" which is actually a single quote character.
I want to know if there is a better way to parse JSON to convert information like "’" to real characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

parseJson will return a JSON object when you pass a json string.

"This function will parse a string formatted according to RFC4627 and return an equivalent BrightScript object (consisting of booleans, integer and floating point numbers, strings, roArray, and roAssociativeArray objects). If the string is not syntactically correct, Invalid will be returned."

So if "'" is an acceptable type JSON key you should be able to get it.
https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/brightscript/language/global-utility-functions.md#parsejsonjsonstring-as-string-as-object